# Multiple combining of all elements of a string in an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, csv, join

Now I have a problem with joining every element in thetable (see on the picture below)

This is my code:

```
import csv
import string

def remove_cruft(s):
    return s[:-1]

with open('name.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    my_list = [[remove_cruft(item) for item in line] for line in reader]

for i in my_list:
  person1 =  i.append('łem')
  person2 =  i.append('łam')
  person3 =  i.append('ło')

print(my_list)

#string.join(...)
```

I want on output:

```
[robiłem]
[robiłam]
[robiło]
[marudziłem]
[marudziłam]
[marudziło]
[biegałem]
[biegałam]
[biegało]
```

Is possible to make it with 1 method call - example: string.join() ?

[image: join every element]

Comment: Can oyu please provide some of your sample data, and also tell us exactly what it is that you're trying to do?

Comment: Try `[[line[1] + x for x in line[1:]] for line in my_list]`. I think that'll get you what you want.

Comment: This is what i want but i can't use it in to argument: string.join([[line[1] + x for x in line[1:]] for line in my_list])  dosn't solve my problem..

Comment: this was a problem with metod string join. This is correkt code:import csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a problem with metod string join. This is correct code:

```
import csv
import string

def remove_cruft(s):
    return s[:-1]

def add_cruft(s):
    return s


with open('name.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    my_list = [[remove_cruft(item) for item in line] for line in reader]
    #my_list_2 = [[remove_cruft(item) for item in line] for line in reader]
    my_list2 = [[add_cruft(item) for item in line] for line in reader]

print(my_list2)

my_list==my_list2

for i in my_list:
    temp=i[0]
    title = "Czas przeszły: "
    i[0] =title + temp + 'lem'
    i.append(temp + 'lam')
    i.append(temp + 'lo')

for i1 in my_list2:
    temp1=i[0]
    title1 = "Czas przeszły:     "
    i[0] =title1 + temp1 + 'laaem'
    i.append(temp1 + 'laaam')
    i.append(temp1 + 'lsso')

print(my_list)
print(my_list2)

with open('output1.csv','w') as output:

    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for val in my_list:
      writer.writerow([val])
```

THX for Answer ! :)